# How to determine if date is weekend in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

If I have a date coming into a function, how can I tell if it's a weekend day?

Comment: Note that some countries have Friday and Saturday as weekend  (as I've mentioned in the answers) so an answer should consider weekend by country https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend

Comment: Is there any way to know if a day is a weekend regardless in which locale we are in, for example using moment.js? Example - Arabic language

Comment: @Guy True see latest simple answer taking care of other countries.

Comment: @Marek please see my latest answer to fix iy

Answer (score 214, accepted):

```
var dayOfWeek = yourDateObject.getDay();
var isWeekend = (dayOfWeek === 6) || (dayOfWeek  === 0); // 6 = Saturday, 0 = Sunday
```

Comment: `d` != `day` :) I would rather call it `dayOfWeek`, it would make more sense to OP.

Comment: This is *not* true for all timezones. For example, in France, the first day of the week will be Monday, not Sunday. Modern time libraries like Moment compensate for this.

Comment: @csvan: `getDay` should always return 0 for sunday and 6 for saturday etc, according to the current timezone settings. (And then it's up to the OP to decide what constitutes a "weekend" according to their requirements.)

Comment: For js, it's probably better if you do `===` instead of `==` when comparing absolute values. Not crucial, but just best practice.

Comment: See https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-week-day. 0 always equals Sunday

Comment: Some countries have Friday and Saturday as weekend so this answer is suitable for the Christian Stackoverflow :-p

Comment: @LukeH a simple modern solution that can handle all Locales is posted. Hope this works for you

Answer (score 63):

```
var isWeekend = yourDateObject.getDay()%6==0;
```

Comment: This says returns true if it's Saturday

Comment: 0%6(Sunday) and 6%6 (Saturday) both have a 0 modulus

Comment: except being voluntary confusing, I don't see any point in this technique.  I personally prefer LukeH's answer. It's only by chance that in this case we can use modulo of 6 instead of 7 to solve our problem.

Comment: Some countries have Friday and Saturday as weekend

Comment: @Guy then the question is if `.getDay()` will result in another value or if the definition of `isWeekend` would be wrong. If its about the variable, I dont care. I guess a 0 will always be sunday, so its fine for me.

Comment: Yes, Sunday will always be 0. It is a matter of UX. If you would like to show a different UI for weekends considering the country's settings is important. For instance in Google Calendar you can choose whether to start the week on Sunday or Monday.

Answer (score 13):

Short and sweet.

`var isWeekend = ([0,6].indexOf(new Date().getDay()) != -1);`

Answer (score 10):

I tried the Correct answer and it worked for certain locales but not for all:

In momentjs Docs: [weekday](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/)
The number returned depends on the locale initialWeekDay, so Monday = 0 | Sunday = 6

So I change the logic to check for the actual DayString('Sunday')

```
const weekday = momentObject.format('dddd'); // Monday ... Sunday
const isWeekend = weekday === 'Sunday' || weekday === 'Saturday';
```

This way you are Locale independent.

Comment: Some countries have Friday and Saturday as weekend

Comment: @Guy You need to adapt the code to meet country needs. As per the wiki you link above some other countries have a single day weekend. `Some countries have adopted a one-day weekend, i.e. either Sunday only (in seven countries), Friday only (in Djibouti, Iran, Palestine and Somalia), or Saturday only (in Nepal). `

Comment: You do not need to use libraries. Simple JS one line code will work for all weekends in any country. Please see latest post.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2020**

There are now multiple ways to achieve this.

1) Using the `day` method to get the days from 0-6:

```
const day = yourDateObject.day();
// or const day = yourDateObject.get('day');
const isWeekend = (day === 6 || day === 0);    // 6 = Saturday, 0 = Sunday
```

2) Using the `isoWeekday` method to get the days from 1-7:

```
const day = yourDateObject.isoWeekday();
// or const day = yourDateObject.get('isoWeekday');
const isWeekend = (day === 6 || day === 7);    // 6 = Saturday, 7 = Sunday
```

Comment: `.isoWeekday()` is a moment.js method, but not specified.

Answer (score 2):

### Update Nov 2023

Since mid-2022, the days of the weekend can be obtained using the `weekInfo` method of `Intl.Locale` instances.

The method is supported in all modern browsers (under Windows, iOS, and Android including Node.js and Deno, with the exception of Firefox as of Nov 2023).

`new Intl.Locale(locale).weekInfo.weekend` will return an array of integers indicating the days of the weekend for the particular locale, where 1 is Monday and 7 is Sunday.

Further information can be found on MDN [Intl.Locale.prototype.getWeekInfo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/getWeekInfo).

Examples:

```
console.log(new Intl.Locale("en-US").weekInfo.weekend);
//[6,7]  // weekend is days 6 and 7 (Sat and Sun) in USA

console.log(new Intl.Locale("ar-EG").weekInfo.weekend);
// [5,6]  // weekend is days 5 and 6 (Fri and Sat) in Egypt

console.log(new Intl.Locale("en-IN").weekInfo.weekend);
// [7]  // weekend is day 7 (Sunday) in India
```

Unlike the `Date.getDay()` method which returns the weekday number with `0` meaning Sunday, the `weekInfo.weekend` returns Sunday as day number `7`. Monday is day `1`.

The function below tests, if the weekday number returned from `Date.getDay()` (after correction for Sunday) is included in the array of integers returned from the `weekInfo.weekend` method.

```js
function isWeekend(date , locale="en-US") {
return new Intl.Locale(locale).weekInfo.weekend.includes(date.getUTCDay()||7);
}

//==== test for 2023-11-24 (Friday) =======
let myDate = new Date("2023-11-24");
console.log(isWeekend(myDate));         // false in USA
console.log(isWeekend(myDate,"ar-EG")); // true  in Egypt
console.log(isWeekend(myDate,"en-IN")); // false in India
console.log(isWeekend(myDate,"fa-IR")); // true  in Iran
```

The following table summarises the days of the workweek and weekends as detailed on [table of Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend).

| Total Countries | Days of Weekend | Total Working Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 95 | Saturday and Sunday | 5 |
| 18 | Friday and Saturday | 5 |
| 1 | Friday and Sunday | 5 |
| 10 | Sunday | 6 |
| 4 | Friday | 6 |
| 1 | Saturday | 6 |
|  |  |  |
| Source: Wikipedia (Nov 2023) |  |  |

Comment: ATM this is unfortunately NOT supported by Firefox.

Comment: True. I have already stated this in my answer above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested most of the answers here and there's always some issue with the Timezone, Locale, or when start of the week is either Sunday or Monday.

Below is one which I find is more secure, since it relies on the **name** of the weekday and on the **en** locale.

```
let startDate = start.clone(),
    endDate = end.clone();

let days = 0;
do {
    const weekday = startDate.locale('en').format('dddd'); // Monday ... Sunday
    if (weekday !== 'Sunday' && weekday !== 'Saturday') days++;
} while (startDate.add(1, 'days').diff(endDate) <= 0);

return days;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current version, you should use

```
    var day = yourDateObject.day();
    var isWeekend = (day === 6) || (day === 0);    // 6 = Saturday, 0 = Sunday
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .getDay() method on the Date object to get the day.

Check if it is 6 (Saturday) or 0 (Sunday)

```js
var givenDate = new Date('2020-07-11');
var day = givenDate.getDay();
var isWeekend = (day === 6) || (day === 0) ? 'It's weekend': 'It's working day';
    
console.log(isWeekend);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
 if( n == 6 )
console.log("Its weekend!!");
else
console.log("Its not weekend");
```

Answer (score -1):

The following outputs a boolean whether a date object is during «***opening***» hours, excluding weekend days, and excluding nightly hours between `23H00` and `9H00`, while taking into account the client time zone offset.

Of course this does not handle special cases like holidays, but not far to ;)

```js
let t = new Date(Date.now()) // Example Date object
let zoneshift = t.getTimezoneOffset() / 60
let isopen = ([0,6].indexOf(t.getUTCDay()) === -1) && (23 + zoneshift  < t.getUTCHours() === t.getUTCHours() < 9 + zoneshift)

// Are we open?
console.log(isopen)
```

```html
<b>We are open all days between 9am and 11pm.<br>
Closing the weekend.</b><br><hr>

Are we open now?
```

Alternatively, to get the day of the week as a locale *Human* string, we can use:

```js
let t = new Date(Date.now()) // Example Date object

console.log(
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { weekday: 'long'}).format(t) ,
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-FR', { weekday: 'long'}).format(t) ,
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ru-RU', { weekday: 'long'}).format(t)
)
```

Beware `new Intl.DateTimeFormat` is slow inside loops, a simple associative array runs way faster:

```js
console.log(
  ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"][new Date(Date.now()).getDay()]
)
```

Answer (score -3):

Simply add 1 before modulo

```
var isWeekend = (yourDateObject.getDay() + 1) % 7 == 0;
```

Comment: This works only if you consider Sunday to be the whole weekend.

Comment: @cpburnz most of the countries do. only a few start the week with sunday.

Comment: @bokkie Then that's a vital piece of information that should be added to your answer.