# check if date is a weekend or not javascript

Tags: javascript, date, weekend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to determine if date is weekend in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551795/how-to-determine-if-date-is-weekend-in-javascript)

I'm tryng to do something for checkinf onload if date is a weekend or not, I wtitten this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getdate()
{
    var items = new Array();
    var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("date");

    for(var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++)
    {
        items[i] = document.getElementById("date" + (i+1)).value;
    }

    return items;
}
</script>
```

This script will be executed onLoad, but I don't know how to check if dates are weekend or not What I would like to do is that if a date is satturday or sunday to change it for monday.

I've done this using php doing an array and changing it but using php is not adapted for that.

Comment: Yes on the duplicate. `yourdate.getDay() == 0 || yourdate.getDay() == 6` is the short answer though

Comment: What is the format of data in array `items`

Comment: is there a way I can adapt this to my code doing something like as Ive done in php "for each" I don't know how to adapt it

Comment: format are from mysql but I've change them using date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date)) because I use european format

Comment: you must research before ask.

Comment: now it give me something like that Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input edit_scenario.php:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: getdate is not defined edit_scenario.php:138

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply;

```
     var yourDate = new Date('2012-08-26');
            if(yourDate.getDay() === 6){
               //saturday
            }
          if(yourDate.getDay() === 0){ 
              //sunday
            }

   // if date is in 28-08-2012 format
     var date = '26-08-2012';
     yourDate = new Date(date.split('-')[2],date.split('-')[1],date.split('-')[0]);
         if(yourDate.getDay() === 6){
               //saturday
            }
          if(yourDate.getDay() === 0){ 
              //sunday
            }
```

Comment: Ive done this but it does not work jsfiddle.net/SbcWr

Comment: provide html code as well or just tell me what do you get from document.getElementsByClassName("date") ??

Comment: see edited code...hope it will help

Comment: Dear Sir I try to do like that But days are not changing

Comment: what do you mean by 'days are not changing'?

Answer (score 2):

Parse the date, and then use [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay):

```
for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
    items[i] = document.getElementById("date" + (i+1)).value;
    var itemDtParts = item[i].split("-");
    var itemDt = new Date(itemDtParts[2], itemDtParts[1] - 1, itemDtParts[0]);
    if (itemDt.getDay() == 6 || itemDt.getDay() == 0) {
      // weekend
    }
}
```

Comment: in item it is stored as d-m-Y

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski: Can you give me an example string? `28-08-2012`?

Comment: for example for today which is the 28th day of august 2012 we use 28-08-2012

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski: Ok, I've edited my answer to parse that date format.

Comment: Dear Joao I've done this but it does not work http://jsfiddle.net/SbcWr/

Comment: dear Joao Ive done this but it does not work http://jsfiddle.net/SbcWr/