# How to display dates and months on header

Tags: html

I want to build a table with header containing Months and dates without weekends on the top as the following:

[image].

Using HTML or JavaScript. Anyone please help me on this

Comment: So you basically want a calendar without weekends? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes.. Artyom.. we want without weekend I tried searching built in component. But didn't

Answer (score 0):

I would be creating a table using JavaScript. You could cycle through the dates that you wish to display. Run the check that is detailed in the answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551795/how-to-determine-if-date-is-weekend-in-javascript). It will check to determine if the date is a weekend or note. Code from question:

```
var day = yourDateObject.getDay();
var isWeekend = (day == 6) || (day == 0);    // 6 = Saturday, 0 = Sunday
```

Using that as the validating statement in your loop, you can then just call `document.createElement('th')` to create your header. It's pretty simple from there.

Comment: You can use the upvote/accept answer button if this answer helped you.

Comment: Can we display the above one using SVG..?

Comment: If you have the graphics, then I would assume so...Just create a new svg instead.